# Unsolvable system of equations - NSolve takes too long to run

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of 6 equations. Here is my input values:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
kB = 1.380649*10^-23; 
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.304;
f = 96485.33212;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
k0 = 10^(-9.8);
rhoBbar = 1*nA;
rhoCbar = 1*nA;
rhoDbar = 1*nA;
vA = 1.6*10^-30; 
vB = 1.6*10^-30; 
vC = 2.48*10^-29; 
vD = 2.48*10^-29; 
vBb = {8.6}*10^-29;
vBnb = 5*vBb;
vCb = 1*10^-28;
u1 = u2 = u3 = -1.5/beta;
vW = 0.03*10^-27;
dStern = 1000*10^(-12);
pSite = 0.5*nA;
```

The equations:

```
c = -((2*eps*eps0)/(e^2*beta)) {(*(10^(-14)/rhoDbar) +*)
    rhoBbar + rhoCbar + rhoDbar};
eqn1Squared = (-2*pBnb - 2*pBb + pC + pSiO)^2 == (2*eps*eps0)/(
     beta*e^2) {(*10^(-14)/rhoDbar Exp[beta*(-e*phi0 +vD*osmP0)]+*)
      rhoBbar*Exp[beta*(-2*e*phi0 - vB*osmP0)] + 
       rhoCbar*Exp[beta*(e*phi0 - vC*osmP0)] + 
       rhoDbar*Exp[beta*(e*phi0 - vD*osmP0)]} + c;
eqn2 = pSiO == 
   pSite*(k0*rhoDbar*Exp[beta*(e*phi0 - vD*osmP0)])/(
    10^(-14) + k0*rhoDbar*Exp[beta*(e*phi0 - vD*osmP0)]);
eqn3 = (pBnb - pC)/(pSiO - pBnb - 2*pBb) == 
   Exp[-beta*(u1 + 2*e*phi0 + osmP0*vBnb)];
eqn4 = (Sqrt[2]*pBb)/(pSiO - pBnb - 2*pBb) == 
   Exp[-0.5*beta*(u3 + 2*e*phi0 + osmP0*vBb)];
eqn5 = pC/(pBnb - pC) == Exp[beta*(u1 - u2 + e*phi0 - osmP0*vCb)];
eqn6 = osmP0 == -(1/(beta*vW))*
    Log[(1(*-(10^(-14)/rhoDbar) Exp[beta*(-e*phi0 +vD*osmP0)]*vA*)- 
        pBb*vBb/dStern - pBnb*vBnb/dStern - pC*vCb/dStern - 
        rhoDbar*Exp[beta*(e*phi0 - vD*osmP0)]*vD)/(1(*-(10^(-14)/
        rhoDbar) *vA*)- rhoBbar*vB - rhoCbar*vC - rhoDbar*vD)];
```

To solve this set of equations, I first reduce the system of 6 equations (`eqn1Squared`, `eqn2`, `eqn3`, `eqn4`, `eqn5`, `eqn6`) to a system of 2 equation (`eqn1` and `eqn6`):

```
solution2345 = Solve[{eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5}, {pSiO, pBnb, pBb, pC}];
eqns16Squared = {eqn1Squared, eqn6} /. solution2345[[1]];
```

Then, I use NSolve to solve `eqn1Squared` and `eqn6` together:

```
simplified = Simplify[eqns16Squared];
solution16Squared = NSolve[simplified, {phi0, osmP0}];
```

But the code takes forever to run, and I have never been able to get any results so far. I also tried rationalize the system of 2 equations (`eqn1Squared` and `eqn6`) before solving:

```
rationalized = eqns16Squared // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
solution16Squared = NSolve[rationalized, {phi0, osmP0}];
```

However, the code also takes forever to run, and it will return this error:

> PolynomialGCD::lrgexp

I have taken a look at the final sets of equations (`eqns16Squared`), and I notice the exponents are in extreme values. I suspect that this is causing the code to take forever to run. May I know is there anyway to simplify my current system of equations to facilitate the solving process?

Comment: Looks like a minor scrape-n-paste issue. If I scrape-and-paste-and-evaluate I see `eqn1Squared` but no `eqn1` and `eqns16` but no `eqns16squared` The second one I can guess what to do, the first is less certain.

Comment: @Bill I had a typo when I typed my question, everything had been corrected for `eqn1Squared` and `eqns16Squared`. `eqn1` is the first equation and `eqns16` is the system of equations with first and sixth equations. I named them as `eqn1` and `eqns16` intially, and later on, I changed the names to `eqn1Squared` and `eqns16Squared` because I squared both sides of `eqn1`.

Comment: You appear to be using List brackets in place of parentheses (e.g., definitions of vBb, c, eqn1Squared). Don't do that. Don't wait until the end to Rationalize. Rationalize early and do any numeric calculations with arbitrary precision (specify WorkingPrecision) rather than machine precision.